# TYPO3 extbase how to end a script properly

Tags: php, typo3, scheduled-tasks, extbase

I have a scheduler task running every few minutes that triggers a CommandController. If I encounter a specific scenario I need to end the execution of this task.

I do this with a simple `exit()`.
But it looks like extbase does not like that, since the scheduler tasks is marked as running when ending the script like this and therefore the next execution of the task will never happen.

Is there a proper way of ending a script in extbase so also the scheduler is noticed that the execution of the script is "finished"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return true if your scheduler task did the job you excepted and false if it fails.